# Trying to exit a while loop using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm fairly new to Python and I've made a random number guessing game. The problem I'm running into is I cannot get my program to exit the while loop when I reach 0 lives instead it tells me i have -1 lives or -2 lives etc. I've looked over the code and I'm struggling to see the flaw in my logic/programming. Any help with this would be appreciated!

```
from random import randint


randomnumber = randint(1, 30)

print("Welcome to the number guessing game!")

game = False
lives = 3

while not game or lives == 0:

    playerguess = int(input("Please enter a number between 1 and 30: "))

    if playerguess > 30 or playerguess < 1:
        print("Please only enter numbers between 1 and 30")
    elif playerguess == randomnumber:
        print("Correct!")
        game = True
    elif playerguess == randomnumber - 1 or playerguess == randomnumber + 1:
        lives -= 1
        print("You were so close! You now have", lives, "lives remaining!")
    else:
        lives -= 1
        print("Not even close! You now have", lives, "lives remaining!")

if game:
    print("Congratulations you won with ", lives, "lives remaining!")
else:
    print("Sorry you ran out of lives!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this `while not game and lives > 0`.

Your current statement `while not game or lives == 0`, means that the loop can continue if lives are not 0 **or** `not game` since you can run out of lives without changing `game` to `True` the loop won't exit.

This new condition will only allow to run the game if you have more than 0 lives and `not game` which will fix the issue.

```
Congratulations you won with  3 lives remaining!
...
Not even close! You now have 0 lives remaining!
```

Sorry you ran out of lives!

Comment: Thank you for the reply - very helpful explanation

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is wrong:

`while not game and lives > 0:`

You want to loop while the game is not complete (`not game`) and while the number of lives is greater than 0 (`lives > 0`).

Answer (score 0):

You should improve your while conditions to `while not game and lives > 0` or add a break command in your while loop that will only get called whenever you reach `lives < 1`:

```
...
while not game:

    playerguess = int(input("Please enter a number between 1 and 30: "))

    if playerguess > 30 or playerguess < 1:
        print("Please only enter numbers between 1 and 30")
    elif playerguess == randomnumber:
        print("Correct!")
        game = True
    elif playerguess == randomnumber - 1 or playerguess == randomnumber + 1:
        lives -= 1
        print("You were so close! You now have", lives, "lives remaining!")
    else:
        lives -= 1
        print("Not even close! You now have", lives, "lives remaining!")

    #get out of loop if player died
    if lives < 1:
        break

if game:
...
```

Comment: Hi George. I've seen a couple of your answers, and they seem very helpful. Could I ask you to take care about case, formatting and punctuation also? Stack Overflow answers are intended to be a bit closer to documentation-quality than a general forum, and if they can be as readable as possible first time around, it will save a volunteer editor from some work. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing @halfer, I will make sure to be more careful when it comes to formatting my answers. Thank you.